# "Failed to Parse Access Policies for table" in vertica

Tags: vertica

I have renamed one column name `cust_addr` to `customer_address` from `Customers` table, using below query:

```
Alter table Customers rename column cust_addr to customer_address;
```

Now, when am trying to access the data from Customers table, am getting below error:

```
Select * from Customers;

[Code: 6482, SQL State: VX001]  [Vertica][VJDBC](6482) ERROR: Failed to parse Access Policies for table "Customers" [Column "cust_addr" does not exist]
```

I have checked this `cust_addr` column is not present in `Customers` tables now. But still getting this error.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Find the access policy that is not working now:

```
SELECT * FROM access_policy WHERE table_name='Customers' AND column_name='cust_addr';
```

Keep that information.

Then -

```
DROP ACCESS POLICY ON Customer FOR COLUMN cust_addr;
```

.. And create the new access policy for `customer_address`.